# apt-mirror not downloading packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, repository, apt-mirror

I am mirroring an Ubuntu 14.04 repo with apt-mirror, but I am facing some troubles when downloading packages. Sometimes apt-mirror gets the index files and says it has to download about XXX Mb, but it does so in half a second (of course, it downloads nothing). Later I try to use my mirror, and I see the inexistent packages. I repeat the process and again I get the same error.

The curious thing is that if I point my sources.list directly to the repo I am mirroring I can use it normally, the packages are there.

This is the output I get from apt-mirror:

```
Downloading 345 index files using 8 threads...
Begin time: Wed Dec  2 11:23:14 2015
[8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]... 
End time: Wed Dec  2 11:23:16 2015

Processing tranlation indexes: [TTTTTTTTTT]

Downloading 187 translation files using 8 threads...
Begin time: Wed Dec  2 11:23:16 2015
[8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]... 
End time: Wed Dec  2 11:23:23 2015

Processing indexes: [PPPPPPPPPP]

784.1 MiB will be downloaded into archive.
Downloading 302 archive files using 8 threads...
Begin time: Wed Dec  2 11:23:30 2015
[8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]... 
End time: Wed Dec  2 11:23:32 2015

1.5 GiB in 721 files and 0 directories can be freed.
Run /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/clean.sh for this purpose.

Running the Post Mirror script ...
(/var/spool/apt-mirror/var/postmirror.sh)

/bin/sh: 0: Can't open /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/postmirror.sh

Post Mirror script has completed. See above output for any possible errors.
```

Any idea of what is going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give the content of `/var/spool/apt-mirror/var/archive-log.0` in the question?

Comment: Hi @TungTran an thank you for your interest. I'm sorry, but I don't have `/var/spool/apt-mirror/var/archive-log.0` anymore. I switched to `debmirror` which is working well.

Comment: Great to know you had your solution :)

Comment: @greenLED If you found an answer could you post it in the answer section below? That way other people can benefit and the question can be marked solved.

Comment: @Magellan I suggest asking a new question since it doesn't seem anyone can answer this one. That way it is easier for people to address your specific problem :)

Comment: @Seth as he commented, he switched to `debmirror` instead of continuing with `apt-mirror` which didn't work for him.